# Shapefile projection files

Tags: coordinates, gis, shapefile, geo, map-projections

I'm working with some open data involving Shapefiles and I've managed to convert the data to GeoJSON and extract the coordinates of the points (along with other information). However the coordinates do not appear to be latitudinal/longitudinal coordinates:

```
[ 368667.2455000002, 5009510.4067 ]
[ 367885.47140000015, 5019804.3237 ]
[ 395852.80260000005, 5027699.9354 ]
[ 379358.1364000002, 5036798.5747 ]
[ 351968.9621000001, 5017404.8727 ]
[ 375123.64269999973, 5033338.467499999 ]
[ 378133.7736999998, 5032617.237500001 ]
[ 385791.0351, 5010557.9144 ]
[ 349796.77770000044, 5013571.1559999995 ]
[ 367271.0566999996, 5030212.897399999 ]
[ 378808.0292999996, 5013921.017100001 ]
[ 336650.69820000045, 5039983.886399999 ]
[ 364178.05599999987, 5015957.9625 ]
[ 362715.9132000003, 5023112.371200001 ]
[ 351321.0865000002, 5013763.298699999 ]
[ 373254.0789000001, 5026533.7453000005 ]
[ 355235.6211000001, 5016957.0644000005 ]
[ 327797.9938000003, 5036758.195699999 ]
[ 362836.86930000037, 5015895.811000001 ]
[ 375479.41530000046, 5001245.2017 ]
```

Upon further research, I found that I have to "project" these coordinates with respect to the data in the PRJ file:

```
PROJCS["City of Ottawa",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101]
        ],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0],
        UNIT["Degree", 0.0174532925199433]
    ],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting", 304800.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing", 0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian", -76.5],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor", 0.9999],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin", 0.0],
    UNIT["Meter", 1.0]
]
```

I've already read [What does an esri projection file represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987279/what-does-an-esri-projection-file-represent) and subsequently, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/does-re-projecting-an-esri-shapefile-only-update-the-content-of-the-prj-file/2386#2386. Though they describe what projection files do/are, there is no discussion on how the transformation is done.

Unlike Shapefiles, I haven't been able to find a specification on PRJ files. Is there an algorithm that is used to transform the coordinates to lat/long coordinates?

I'm also open to using libraries but they will need to be compatible with either Android (GeoTools did not work for me) or JavaScript (Node).

Comment: do you have updates on this, after so many years? How to convert those coordinates into GPS coordinates (wgs84) using that projection file using nodeJS or JS?

Answer (score 0):

How the transformation is actually done can be extremely complicated, especially if you're going between datums (such as NAD83 to WGS84, etc.)  There are a ton of tools out there that can do this, but I'm not that familiar with mobile stuff but I know some people have gotten GDAL and OGR to build on Android.  See http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid.

You will need to find the EPSG code for your data.  From what you posted, these coordinates are in EPSG:32189 (MTM Zone 9).  To find this I used the website http://prj2epsg.org, where you can upload a .prj file and it will find the EPSG code for you.  You can view more information about that projection at spatialreference.org.  That site has several useful features, such as downloadable prj files for each projection, and a proj4 file for the proj4 library mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Typically, NAD83 and WGS84 are within one meter of each other. For practical purposes they can be considered to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest GeoJSON spec ([RFC7946](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946)), the CRS must be WGS84(lat/lng). Tools such as the [GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html) suite assume the CRS of your output is in WGS84.

That said, the reprojection step must be done while or before converting from shapefile to GeoJSON.

For example, with `ogr2ogr` from GDAL, and provided the PRJ companion file is in the same directory as the shapefile (the coordinate system will be read from the PRJ file with no need to specify an input EPSG code),

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.json input.shp
```

Note that in recent GDAL versions there is no need to force the output coordinate system to be WGS84, as explained in the first paragraph. Previous syntax would be,

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f GeoJSON output.json input.shp
```

You can use a NodeJS wrapper for `ogr2ogr`

For example,

https://github.com/wavded/ogr2ogr

Corresponding NPM package,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ogr2ogr

EDIT 1:

Alternatively, SWIG generated NodeJS bindings for GDAL can be used,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal

EDIT 2:

Nevertheless if the OP really wants to convert a GeoJSON still in [EPSG:32198](https://epsg.io/32189-1696) to a GeoJSON in WGS84 this will do the job:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -s_srs EPSG:32198 -f GeoJSON output.json input.json
```

Note that GDAL is distributed with an EPSG Database from where it will be read the following string:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-76.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=304800 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

That corresponds to the PRJ file in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, the best solution I found and which I implemented (and it's [working](https://github.com/jfoclpf/geo-pt-api)) resides on using the library [proj4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proj4). But I know this library exists also for Python.

In Javascript it would be:

```js
var firstProjection = 'PROJCS["NAD83 / Massachusetts Mainland",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",42.68333333333333],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",41.71666666666667],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",41],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-71.5],PARAMETER["false_easting",200000],PARAMETER["false_northing",750000],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26986"],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH]]';
var secondProjection = "+proj=gnom +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=6300000 +y_0=6300000 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";
//I'm not going to redefine those two in latter examples.
proj4(firstProjection,secondProjection,[2,5]);
// [-2690666.2977344505, 3662659.885459918]
```

If only 1 projection is given then it is assumed that it is being projected from WGS84 (standard of GPS).

```js
proj4(firstProjection,[-71,41]);
// [242075.00535055372, 750123.32090043]
```

Comment: GDAL is using PROJ under the wood. There are several SWIG generated PROJ bindings one of them being PyProj (python bindings). Proj4js is a parcial PROJ rewriting in JavaScript.